# Why won't SoundCloud API respond until I click three times on play on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, soundcloud

I've created my own Music Player with the SoundCloud API and everything works fine on desktops. However, for some reason it takes at least three clicks on the play button on a mobile phone before the music player actually starts. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Below is my jQuery code. my music player is a JS Object and this is the play method:

```
//<-- PLAY TRACK -->
this.playTrack = function(track, number) {

    var that = this;

    SC.stream("/tracks/" + track, {onfinish: function() { 
        that.onFinish(number);
    }}, 

    function (sound) {
        that.stream = sound;
        that.currentTrack = track;

        var trackName = $(that.track_links[number]).html();
        trackName = trackName.replace(/\d.\s/, "");
        that.player.find(".current-track").css("display", "block");
        that.player.find(".current-track").children("p").html(trackName);

        sound.play({
            whileplaying: function () {
                that.player.find(".progress").css('width', ((sound.position / sound.duration) * 100) + '%');
                that.player.find(".playtime").html(that.minutesAndSeconds(sound.position));
            },
        });

        that.updateProgress(sound);

    that.playing = true;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Anyone who have experienced the same issue? It's quite peculiar...

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem as well - everything was working fine on desktop, but, the player took to attempts on mobile before it would play. I noticed this in the console:

```
Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

The play is actually initiated by a click - so I'm not sure why Soundmanager was blocking it like this. My solution was to initiate the initial 'play' event when the user clicks on an element - in my case, the one that brings the player into view. I still get the error - but, the next click works.

Comment: Do you mean that you trigger the play function (or method) when the user clicks to get the player into view?

If that's a yes, I have a problem since my SC player is already in view when the page loads.